# Java boolean CLI options

Tags: java, apache-commons, getopt

I'm getting my feet wet with the Apache Commons CLI library for command-line parsing.  It works fine for String-valued options, but I'm not sure how to cleanly handle boolean-valued command-line flags.  I've tried this:

```
    CommandLineParser parser = new GnuParser();
    Options options = new Options();
    options.addOption(new Option("parseOnly", "Only parse"));
    CommandLine cl = parser.parse( options, args );

    if( cl.hasOption( "parseOnly" ) )
    PARSE_ONLY = (Boolean) cl.getParsedOptionValue( "parseOnly" );
```

But this fails with a `NullPointerException` on the file line, because `cl.getParsedOptionValue()` returns `null` and that can't be cast to `Boolean`.

`cl.hasOption( "parseOnly" )` returns true or false, but it's not clear from the docs what that means - does it mean the user specified it and it could be either true or false?  Or does it mean the flag is activated?  What if you want a flag to be default true, and let the user turn it off (like --noParseOnly in other getopt parsers)?

I'll appreciate any suggestions people have, including RTFMs - I'm sure this is well-trodden ground.  Thanks.

Comment: use `Boolean.valueOf(cl.getParsedOptionValue("parseOnly"))` to convert a String to boolean

Comment: `cl.getParsedOptionValue()` doesn't return a String, it returns an Object, and the docs say "Return a version of this Option converted to a particular type."  Unfortunately it doesn't say how that particular type is determined.

Answer (score 8):

For boolean options (or flags), if the option is found then the option value is true, otherwise the value is false.

Therefore, if a user specifies `-parseOnly`, then that means that it is true. If -parseOnly is not present, then the user does not want it and it is false.

So all you need to do is:

```
 if( cl.hasOption( "parseOnly" ) ){
    //do something
 }
```

Another point: Don't cast a string to boolean. Instead, use `Boolean.valueOf(cl.getOptionValue("parseOnly"))` to convert a String to boolean.

Comment: In that case, how do I handle an option with default value true, which I want the caller to be able to turn off?  Make a separate `noParseOnly` option (but then I quickly run out of single-letter abbreviations)?  Let it take a value like `--parseOnly=0` (but then the processing gets more complicated)?  Not sure.

Comment: Regarding `Boolean.valueOf()` - see my comment above, `getParsedOptionValue()` returns an Object (of unknown type), not a String.

Comment: use getOptionValue() which returns a string, instead of getParsedOptionValue().

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the source files and [getParsedOptionValue](http://tinyurl.com/ks9jm6z)() parses the option string argument according to Option.getType(), which you can set with OptionBuilder.withType(). The problem is it [only works with a limited set of types](http://tinyurl.com/kxylswk) (Number, Date, etc) and, for instance, it doesn't even work with Integer.

That said, you should use zero-argument flag options for booleans, not options with arguments, cause the user usually expects to type '--parse-only' or nothing at all, not '--parse-only true|false'. That's probably the reason why getParsedOptionValue() doesn't support the Boolean type.